# QMail unable to send email to gmail.com or any address outside the network

Tags: unix, email

I installed qmail and I am able to send and receive emails when i add  the address within the network in the /var/qmail/control/smtproutes file.

Say I create a virtual domain in my windows machine as abc.com and add "abc.com:" in smtproutes, then email delivery is successful.

But when i directly send emails to outside domain, i get  error
" Sorry,_I_wasn't_able_to_establish_an_SMTP_connection".

Is this a firewall issue? What could I be missing?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this belong on SuperUser?

Comment: No, it's a mailserver question. Def. here. Is DNS working on the box?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Eliminate the firewall issue** by testing that you can actually connect out to an external mail server's port 25 from your mail server. You can do this by `telnet <external mail server> 25` and see if you get the welcome message.
2. **Eliminate the SSL issue** by testing that the connection is actually accepting clear-text transmissions. It is possible that `STARTTLS` is required.
3. Still thikning about it. Will edit my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

How many NICs are in this server?  It's possible that qmail is trying to make an outbound connection on a non-functioning NIC or using a route that doesn't exist.  
What does `netstat -r` show?

Answer (score 0):

It could well be a firewall issue. You will need outgoing port 25 opened to ANY destination address on the firewall.